# Why does this if require a default?

Tags: php, if-statement

This is the if:

```
Session::has('tk') ? Session::get('tk') : 1;
```

I would like to skip the : 1 but then it fails for some reason while tk is allways set in another if?

Comment: what do you mean "skip the 1"?

Comment: If you use the short version, you need to had a else

Comment: @Dinistro is correct - ternary operator has a strict syntax http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: You can use `$v = S::has('k') ? S::get('k') : $v;` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you already know that `tk` has a value, then you don't need to use `has()` function to check it.

Use just:

```
Session::get('tk');
```

Comment: he wrote "while tk is allways set in another if?" so i understand, that he already knows that at this point

Answer (score 1):

In a short if, you need to define both:

```
<?php
    $var = ($someThing) ? true: false;
```

If you don't want to do that, take a regular `if-statement`

```
<?php
    if ($someThing) {
        $var = true;
    }
```

Comment: note that this particular statement should be written as `$var = ! $someThing`

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator, as it is called  `boolean ? true_value : false_value`

always needs a boolean (comparison), a value to return if the boolean is true, and a value to return when the boolean is false.

I would use it like

```
$tk = Session::has('tk') ? Session::get('tk') : null;
```

making $tk contain the session value, or null if there is no session value.

Comment: small typo in your ternary, colon instead question mark

Answer (score 0):

I would use it like

```
$check = Session::has('tk') ? Session::get('tk') : 1;
```